# In libgdx ParticleEffect how do you reduce the size of the effect without reducing the number of particles?

Tags: android, libgdx, particles

I am finding it quite tricky to reduce the (overall) size of the effect I went to the .p file of my effect and went to the scaling section of the file and changed the numbers around for the attributes 'highMin' and 'highMax' but it doesn't seem to be doing the required effect that I want. It reduces the size, but it is not the same effect as I created it effectively loses some particles.

Is there any way to reduce the overall size of the effect without losing some of the particles.

Comment: Reduce the lifetime. And use the editor for it. It does show you how much particle are activ and so on and you can easy manipulate it.

Comment: when I mean size I dont mean time I mean size. Like you know if you have a picture which is 64 x 64 how do you scale it down to 32 x 32 without losing anything ?

Comment: i am sorry missread. scaling inside of the effect or on runtime. scaling of 0.5 is 50% size. But i would recomend to use a smaler picture instead of scaling but thats your choice.